# How to make firebase dynamic link differentiate between free and paid version of the same app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

In Firebase dynamic links, we have to specify the package name in the link itself in order to direct the user to the app.
So, if I use Firebase dynamic links to direct users to my free app, how will the same link forward them to the paid app as well? (considering that the free and paid versions can't have the same package name).
Any way to handle this case?

Comment: Hi drishit96. You're scenario is a bit confusing. Could you expound? Are you asking for a dynamic way to decide on which app you want your *dynamic link* would link to? Some additional sample scenarios would help. Cheers!

Comment: @AL., I just want that, if the user has the free version, then the dynamic link should open the free app or else if user has paid version then the link should open the paid version, without any further input from user.

Answer (score 2):

This currently isn't possible since the Dynamic Link decides which app to send the user to based on the `androidPackageName` you specified in the link.

You could try submitting a feature request for sending a Dynamic link to multiple package names over at the [Firebase support page](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Do you know of any alternatives to do it?

Comment: This is correct, and there aren't any workarounds unfortunately. We are aware of this issue and pain point, and this feature is on our roadmap. We do not have any immediate plans to support multiple apps with one link right now, though.